# How to use pandas groupby, grouper with ngroup?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a date time column. I am trying to group based on 24 hour window but I am not sure what I'm missing. Please let me know where am i going wrong.

For example my dataframe is as below

```
                Dates
0 2021-07-26 07:30:00
1 2021-07-26 13:05:00
2 2021-07-28 08:00:00
3 2021-07-29 00:36:00
4 2021-07-29 16:15:00
```

I am trying to group the dataframe and give them a unique number if it falls under a 24 hours window based on the first date in each group.

Meaning it should group and assign a unique number as below. It picks the first value and groups all the row values coming after it where the time falls within the 24 hours window. So in this example it should group everything which fall between (2021-07-26 07:30:00  to 2021-07-27 07:30:00) as 1 and (2021-07-28 08:00:00 to 2021-07-29 08:00:00) as 2 and (2021-07-29 16:15:00 to 2021-07-30 16:15:00) as 3

Expected O/P

```
                 date  groupedbytime
0 2021-07-26 07:30:00   1
1 2021-07-26 13:05:00   1
2 2021-07-28 08:00:00   2
3 2021-07-29 00:36:00   2
4 2021-07-29 16:15:00   3
```

I am using groupby and grouper but I am getting the o/p as below where its grouping as per the days but not as per the 24 hour window. Kindly advise how to approach this

```
tempdf['groupedbytime'] = tempdf.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Dates",freq='24H')).ngroup()+1
```

O/P

```
                 date  groupedbytime
0 2021-07-26 07:30:00   1
1 2021-07-26 13:05:00   1
2 2021-07-28 08:00:00   2
3 2021-07-29 00:36:00   3
4 2021-07-29 16:15:00   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can working with timedeltas created by subtract first value with integer division, for consecutive order is added [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
s = df['Dates'].sub(df['Dates'].iat[0]).dt.total_seconds() // (3600 * 24)
df['groupedbytime'] = pd.factorize(s)[0] + 1
print (df)
                Dates  groupedbytime
0 2021-07-26 07:30:00              1
1 2021-07-26 13:05:00              1
2 2021-07-28 08:00:00              2
3 2021-07-29 00:36:00              2
4 2021-07-29 16:15:00              3
```

With `Grouper`:

```
s = df['Dates'].sub(df['Dates'].iat[0])
s = s.to_frame().groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Dates",freq='24H'))['Dates'].ngroup()
df['groupedbytime'] = pd.factorize(s)[0] + 1
print (df)
0 2021-07-26 07:30:00              1
1 2021-07-26 13:05:00              1
2 2021-07-28 08:00:00              2
3 2021-07-29 00:36:00              2
4 2021-07-29 16:15:00              3
```

Comment: This works thank you for your response @jezrael 
How do I use this on a full dataset with two groupby columns?  Lets say if I have two columns name and date so first I want to group by name then by date and assign unique numbers? so for each name there would be different date groups
Something like 
df.groupby(['name','date']).ngroup()+1 with the grouper

Comment: @Stramzik - Then use `df.groupby(['name',pd.Grouper(key="Dates",freq='24H')]).ngroup()+1`

Comment: this doesn't account for the 24 hours window which I've mentioned above in the main thread. I am confused on how to use the factorizer with the grouper and groupby?

Comment: then use `df.assign(td = s).groupby(['name',pd.Grouper(key="td",freq='24H')])['td'].ngroup()`

Comment: @Stramzik - and factorize is only for consecutive order, som e.g. `1,2,2,7,8,8` is converting to `1,2,2,3,4,4`